# Windows terminal, split panes but the new pane is on the same directory as the previous?

Tags: windows, split, pane, windows-terminal

Might be a little bit of a silly question. The problem is simple, I tend to have two panes, one where I write code, and the other to compile it. I do that with the windows terminal (cmd + vim + Mingw), but something is bothering me. I can split the panes perfectly but after that I have to change directory to the project directory on both panes.. it is really a minor annoyance, but would it be possible for, when I split panes, the second pane going going directly to the directory of the first?

if it's silly, I'm really sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you probably have found a way by this time but the shortcut to open a new pane in the same directory for Windows terminal is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

You can view the image here:
[pane-split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWwO2.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

If you're still interested in this, it [looks like it will be added to Windows Terminal soon](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3158#issuecomment-727026693).

In the interim, I use tmux to workaround this issue.

Comment: Thanks for linking that thread and suggesting tmux. I do have a somewhat speculative question though: are you sure that it will be? They removed the "In-PR" tag ("in production", I assume), so it could be 'done', but the issue hasn't been closed, and they removed that tag a month ago.

Comment: I think it's a feature that will always be of interest to me!
I have since moved to emacs tho.. so I am not using the same set up anymore, but I am thankful that you shared that here :)

Answer (score -4):

I recommend to you use no-native terminals for that kind of tasks, like cmder, conemu. These consoles have solutions for split pane.